# Do I use an article if the word is combination of a proper noun and a common noun?

Tags: articles

Do I use an article if the word is a combination of a proper noun and a common noun? For example, “Microsoft website.”

Would I say “I need to go on the Microsoft website” or “I need to go on Microsoft website”?

I think I’ve seen both cases used, but I haven't been able to find a clear rule on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your example, it would be "I need to go on the Microsoft website" or "I need to go on Microsoft's website".

"I need to go on Microsoft website" is not correct.

The fact that Microsoft is a proper noun doesn't have anything to do with it-- you always need an article in the above sentence, and since there is only one Microsoft website you would be referring to, you use the definite article rather than the indefinite.

Comment: +1 for simplicity.  Grammatically the word 'Microsoft' is a 'noun adjunct' and the word 'website' is the *head noun*, so use of the article *the* is mandatory